# how to use router.navigate on app.component's onInit in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I am trying to navigate to a route on app.component.ts in angular 2
Here's the plunkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/inqrSB

I am trying to get this working :

```
  ngOnInit(){
    if(this._vehicleService.isAuth())
    {
      this.shownavBar=true;
      this._router.navigate('/characters')  //how can i get this
    }
  }
```

The routeConfig is defined in the same component. can someone please suggest me a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the result: http://plnkr.co/edit/JiNQpDFp3kmthMVbJvKt?p=preview

Just change the usage like this:

```
this._router.navigate(['Characters'])  //how can i get this
```

Comment: I am also trying the same with the help of routes imported from Router in angular 2.0 final release. No error, no redirection and  as per latest release @RouteConfig is deprecated from @angular/route. Help me

Comment: @AnkitJ please ask a new question with with a plunker so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this._router.navigate(["Name of your Component"])
```

OR

```
   this._router.navigateByUrl("/where you want")
```